# How can I enable hierarchical indentation for CSS in WebStorm?

Tags: css, formatting, webstorm

I prefer to format my CSS file with hierarchical indentation. It looks like this

```
.some-class {
    background: #ffffff;
}

    .some-class .child-of-some-class {
        background: #ff0000;
    }

        .some-class .child-of-some-class .child-of-child-of-some-class {
            background: #00ff00;
        }

    .some-class .another-child-of-some-class {
        background: #0000ff;
    }
```

This formatting supports in Visual Studio as default, but now I've changed my IDE on WebStorm and can't find the way to enable auto formatting like this. Does anyone know is WebStorm supports this?

Comment: I don't know about WebStorm but I can say that writing your selectors that way is unnecessarily verbose. You should just start with the ultimate class for each element due to the cascading nature of CSS.

Comment: If you really need such cascading -- why not use pre-processor (e.g. Less/Sass) that naturally allows it (and you do not have to repeat parent class name). In final CSS though all the rules will be in 1 column (no indentation -- indentation makes sense for dev time but not production)